# Avoid creating a pdf file on disk to email as attachment in java

Tags: java, pdf, fileoutputstream

I currently have a pdf template (at a specific location) and use this with a generated pdf file that I save to the same location and then merge using PdfStamper. I then attached the newly created pdf to an email. I want to avoid writing the pdf file to disk. I am currently using FileOutputStream:

```
PdfReader pdfTemplate = new PdfReader(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+ 
"invoicepdf/manualSalesInvoiceTemplate.pdf");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+ 
"invoicepdf/manualSalesInvoice.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfTemplate, fileOutputStream);
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
```

then later

```
//add any file attachments to the message
                String filename = getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+ 
"invoicepdf/manualSalesInvoice.pdf";
                MimeBodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
              //use a JAF FileDataSource as it does MIME type detection
                DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
                attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                attachmentBodyPart.setFileName("Invoice" + i_invoiceID + 
".pdf");
              //add the attachment
                multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);
```

I then send the saved manualSalesInvoice.pdf via email as shown but I have to access the server disk again to do it. I was hoping I could just create an object, or can I use memorystream, or tempfile(not sure if this one needs a physical location), or even ByteArrayStream?... I want to avoid reading from disk.

Any ideas would be appreciatated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In-memory way

```java
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;

...

byte[] content = ... // obtain content of PDF-file

ByteArrayDataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(content, "application/pdf");

MimeBodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
attachmentBodyPart.setFileName("file.pdf");

multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);
```